# Pledge overdue when total paid more than pledged

Tags: pledges, civipledge

We have a couple pledges where recorded contributions add up to more than the amount pledged, and it seems to result in some buggy behavior. The balance for these pledges is negative, but there's still a positive "Next Amount" and the status is "Overdue" instead of "Completed". Both pledges are set up with 1 installment of the total pledge amount every 1 month. Image below shows amounts & dates for pledges & payments:

[image: screenshot of pledge report showing 2 paid but overdue pledges]

Is this expected behavior or a bug? Should we be adjusting the total pledge amount when recording payments higher than the pledged amount? This doesn't seem ideal, the option is a bit buried in the form and it seems useful to record/remember that the amount given was more than what was pledged.

Also, how can we can fix these pledges so that they're "Completed" with $0 for "Next Amount"? Editing the scheduled payment didn't seem to work but maybe I didn't use the right combination of values.